# Objects not appearing in the final render

Tags: rendering

By final render i mean when you press F12 to get a image but when i do that one object doesn't appear although its particles appear and I've tried doing things like Ctrl + Alt + H and W but it doesn't change anything i think this is because it un-hides thing n object mode but I'm talking about when you actually RENDER it. Any help is appreciated

Comment: can you share the file? use this website: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes for a Blank render:

- No lights in scene.
- Objects disabled for Render in outliner (camera icon).
- Strips in VSE and Sequencer enabled.
- Objects in different layer, or in a layer disabled in Render Layers.
- Object blocked by other objects.
- Active camera aiming in a different direction.
- An object in the scene set as active camera.
- Any, some or all of the above.